# Recover lost video

Tags: sudo, find, mv

I used youtube-dl to download a video. It saved in my Home directory. Then I did sudo mv *file_name* /Videos but it's not in my Videos directory and also not in Home. I am using sudo find / but it's taking forever. How can I get the file back? It's a whole 2GB and I don't want to download it again!

Answer (score 2):

Your command was wrong. You moved the file to the `/` directory and renamed it to `Videos`.

You can revert it by running

```
sudo mv /Videos ~/file_name
```

For the future, do not use sudo for moving your files and do not add `/` before the directory name.

The correct command to move a file from your home directory to Videos is

```
sudo mv file_name Videos/
```

without `/`, or better

```
sudo mv file_name ~/Videos/
```

Comment: @MrT: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**